# Calculation from GroupBox's (Radio Buttons)

Tags: vb.net

I am new to this and am confused as to why when the calculate button is clicked, the total is way off. Any guidance or pointing out of mistakes would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim IntegerValue1 As Double
Dim IntegerValue2 As Double


Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter
    If RadioGlazed.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue1 = 0.65
    ElseIf RadioSugar.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue1 = 0.65
    ElseIf RadioChocolate.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue1 = 0.85
    ElseIf RadioFilled.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue1 = 1.0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox2.Enter
    If RadioNone.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue2 = 0.0
    ElseIf RadioRegular.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue2 = 1.8
    ElseIf RadioCapp.Checked = True Then
        IntegerValue2 = 2.5
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub ButtonCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCalc.Click

    SubTotal.Text = (IntegerValue1) + (IntegerValue2)

End Sub
```

Comment: you are getting the IntegerValues in the Group Box Enter event - if the user doesnt go there the values wont get set no matter what is selected.  YOu can and should set the `IntegerValueX` vars in the button click event when they cant change anymore before the calc.  Also, try `SubTotal.Text = (IntegerValue1 + IntegerValue2).ToString`

Comment: Thank you for answering I basically took out the group box if/else statements and put all of it in the calculation button event and it worked.

Comment: To add another observation the RadioButton.Checked property is a Boolean you do not have to say If RadioButton.Checked = True that is like saying If True = True. Just say If RadioButton.Checked Then ....

Comment: You are correct, I deleted the "True" parts of the code, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner way to associate a value and capture it would be to assign the value (.65, .85 etc) to the `.Tag` property of each RB and then capture it when they click. This allows you do do away with SELECT CASE or IF/ELSEIF altogether:

```
Private Sub RBGroup1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioGlazed.CheckedChanged, _
         RadioSugar.CheckChanged       
         ' add for each RB in the group

   IntegerValue1 = CType(sender, RadioButton).Tag
   ' may only need:
   'IntegerValue1 =sender.Tag

End Sub
```

One handler allows 1 event to process them all.  Modify the click for one of the RBs in group 2 to do the same for them (this one for `IntegerValue2`).  Now, when the user selects, the value is set.  Be sure to delete the old/extra event handlers and be sure that one RB in each group is selected to start with so the variables get set when the form loads. Also be sure to add a new Handler and its TAG value if you add more doughnuts/cookies etc.